# HTML & PHP headers look fine but accents will still appear as �

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm facing a quite new situation. I'm not an expert about charset, but as far as I know, all the chain should use the same encoding system.

If I put accents directly in the html code, they'll look fine.
However, when I fetch data from my mysql database, all of them will be displayed like this : �, no matter if I echo them in the body or using scripts.

On the page, I have set this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Regarding the database : the server uses UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) `utf8_general_ci`
The table `utf8_general_ci`
The fields `utf8_general_ci`

I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe the data you have in your database was corrupted already. Create a new entry containing some of those characters, and see if you got the same problem then. (FYI, outputting an XML prolog in that position is just nonsense.)

Comment: Which alphabet ?

Comment: Also note that sending a header after you have sent some html output, does not work.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll be giving a try at your tips. @MorganFreeFarm, I'm using roman alphabet